# Chained drop-down menu for custom taxonomy using chained.js

Tags: categories, menus, jquery, taxonomy

I'm trying to get a chained select to work to select a state then a city with that state. (2 fields).

Here is what I've got:

First my function to create the menu using get_categories().

First problem: Not sure what to put for $child to get it to only show child categories.

```
function taxonomy_dropdown($dropID, $exclude, $taxonomy, $parent, $child) {
    $args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'child_of'                 => $child,
        'parent'                   => $parent, 
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 0,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'exclude'                  => $exclude,
        'include'                  => '',
        'number'                   => '',
        'taxonomy'                 => $taxonomy,
        'pad_counts'               => false
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    $menu = '<select name="'.$dropID.'" id="'.$dropID.'" class="postform">';

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $menu .= '<option class="" value="'.$category->name.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
    }   
    $menu .= '</select>';
    echo $menu;
}
```

In my plugin, the function is called like so:

```
<? 
    taxonomy_dropdown('state','','states_category','0'); 
    taxonomy_dropdown('city','','states_category','','1');
?>
```

The second one for 'city' doesn't work because of the above problem of I can't get it to only get the child categories.

So once I get that to work, I should have 2 selects, one showing 'states' and one showing 'cities.'

Now here is where I get lost. I want to use chained.js (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) to turn these two select menus into a chained select.

I'm pretty sure I've enqueued it into my plugin properly:

```
function includeChained() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'chained',
        plugins_url( '/js/chained/chained.min.js' , __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includeChained' );
```

Now I'm totally clueless about how to use jQuery and JavaScript beyond the ultra basics. I tried what the docs show for using the class based usage:

```
<script>
$("#state").chained("#city");
</script>
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Can you get it working in principle on proof of concept, sans WordPress? Live page, demonstrating the issue would probably be helpful as well.

Comment: Ok, Ive got it working now: http://weedstarter.com/add-location/ -- Ive got 2 drop downs, one showing parent categories only and one showing child categories only. From what Ive figured out about how to use chained.js, all I need to do to get it to work is to get the class of the child category options to be the name of the parent category and it should work.

Comment: @JonFurry Please add that as separate answer. You can mark it as solution just two days after that. We'd appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

Code is here: [Wordpress chained categories](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kGlmC/)

I write the same code for categories. You can edit for your needs.
I used the that js plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful. Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.